# Python show part of a browser?

Tags: python

I'm in the mist of building an "application" and need to display a google map to show markers of some locations. I thought I may create a web page with a google map. And then display it if possible in a python GUI (by some api).

Is there any gui api that could back this up?

Comment: is the location constant? or does it change?

Comment: @sameerasy it changes

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/
you will need to add `<iframe>` to the dom document tree

```
def _view_load_finished_cb(self, view, frame):
    doc = frame.get_dom_document()
    nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')
    body = nodes.item(0)

    d = doc.createElement("iframe")
    d.setAttribute('width', 640)
    d.setAttribute('height', 480)
    d.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA')
    body.appendChild(d)
```